# Laravel 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it mus t be defined as a key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When i try to migrate this table in laravel.

Command output is:

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075
>   Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it
>   must be defined as a key

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->bigInteger('post_author', 20);
        $table->text('post_title');
        $table->longText('post_content');
        $table->string('post_status', 20);
        $table->string('comment_status', 20);
        $table->string('post_type', 20);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Comment: how can i add this in auto_increment field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify a size for bigInteger column

```
$table->bigInteger('post_author');
```

Comment: @AnwarulIslam please accept the anwser  and thump up

Comment: I'll accept. but right now i have no permission to giving thumbs up. i am trying to give but i need some reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a size for bigInteger column by following way

```
$table->bigInteger('post_author')->length(20);
```